# Can't Set RecyclerView to be the size of the Phone Screen

Tags: xml, android-layout

I am trying to set Recyclerview to be the height of the whole thing but I get this kind of problem (I want the white space to be filled by the RecyclerView):
I set an item also because I have problems setting up firebasefirestore pagination with items and I decided to do this instead of adding different items in Adapter to avoid null pointer exceptions.

When I run it without being filled it frizzes until it loads up the full ffirestore document (paginator logic works because it triggers that is the on the end of the Recyclerview)
When I set the Hight for example 1000dp it works but the last item gets cuts off.
[ScreenShot of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBkQH.png)

Here is my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bgLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/darker_gray"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/home_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" Radius: "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/km3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" 3 km "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/km5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" 5 km "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/km8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" 8 km "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/km10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" 10 km "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/km15"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" 15 km "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/km30"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" 30 km "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/km50"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" 50 km "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/km100"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" 100 km "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/km500"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text=" 500 km "
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/White">
                <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/nested_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <include
                            layout="@layout/home_header" />
                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/posts_recyclerview"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/darker_gray"
                            android:scrollbars="none" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The top part is already taken by the HorizontalScrollView. If you want them to overlap and have the RecyclerView also in that space, use `FrameLayout` for `id/container_body` instead of a LinearLayout.

Comment: @RobCo doesn't work